# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'FullmessageController.readsql'

Tags: c#

i get the error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'FullmessageController.readsql'

in the following code block:

```
ReadSQL readsql = new ReadSQL();
QueryHandler queryhandler = new QueryHandler(readsql);
```

the Query handler looks like this:

```
IReadSQL _readsql;
public QueryHandler(IReadSQL readsql)
{
    _readsql = readsql;
}
```

ReadSQL looks like this:

```
public class ReadSQL : IReadSQL
{
    public string GetSQLContent(string name)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string location = "ProofofconceptAPI.Classes.Queries." + name;

        using(Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(location))
        {
            using(StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                return streamreader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

why does this give an error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: which line gives error ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach here depends on whether you actually want multiple fields. If you want two fields, one for the `ReadSQL` and one for the `QueryHandler`, you can do that like this, initializing the fields within the constructor:

```
// Names adjusted for convention
class Whatever
{
    private ReadSql readSql;
    private QueryHandler queryHandler;

    public Whatever()
    {
        readSql = new ReadSql();
        queryHandler = new QueryHandler(readSql);
    }
}
```

If you only need a single field (for the `QueryHandler`) then you can just inline the `ReadSQL` in the field initializer:

```
// Names adjusted for convention
class Whatever
{
    private QueryHandler queryHandler = new QueryHandler(new ReadSql());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as @aluan-haddad mentioned I had to initialize it in my constructor like this:

```
QueryHandler queryhandler = new QueryHandler(new ReadSQL());
```